# Nested random effects for testing individual choices when choices are made in a group

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, glmm, nested-data

I'm planning an experiment where individuals' choices will be measured. I want to test individuals' choices before and after an intervention. The problem is the individuals are in groups and cannot be separated. This obviously means choices can't be truly independent.

I could include individual as a random effect nested within group, but would this eliminate the problem of pseudoreplication if group members copy the choice of the first individual?

Answer (score 0):

Group definitely seems to represent a cluster and should be added as a random effect. If your subjects are measured multiple times and subjects remain in their respective groups, you could nest subjects in groups for the random effect term.

And yes, if you account for the clusters via a multilevel/mixed-effects model, then you account for the non-independence between the data points.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry to double check but my advisor isn't sure. This is definitely still the case even if one individual copies another rather than makes the choice itself?